# Keep the sum of two objects updated as one (or both) objects gets updated

Tags: python, class

I want to create a class in Python that implements a `__add__` object method that allows summing two objects of the same class. Let's call this class `Indicator` and the two objects to sum `ind1` and `ind2`. The `Indicator` object has only one property `elements` , which is a dictionary of integer values.

My implementation of `__add__` combines the `elements`  properties of two objects, eventually summing those values with the same key.

```
from __future__ import annotations
import copy
class Indicator:
    def __init__(self, elements={}):
        self.elements = elements

    def __add__(self, other: Indicator):
        new = copy.deepcopy(self)
        new.values =  {k: self.elements.get(k, 0) + other.elements.get(k, 0) for k in set(self.elements) | set(other.elements)}
        return new

ind1 = Indicator({1:1,2:2,3:3})
ind2 = Indicator({1:1,2:2})

new = ind1 + ind2
print('ind1: ',ind1.elements)
print('ind2: ',ind2.elements)
print(new.elements) # {1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 3}
```

I would like `__add__` to return an object whose `elements` property gets updated as one or both objects in the summation get updated along the code flow.

For example,

```
ind1.elements[4] = 4
print(new.elements) # I would like this to be {1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 3, 4:4}

ind1.elements[1] = 3
print(new.elements) # I would like this to be {1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 3, 4:4}
```

How can I do it?

**EDIT**

First of all, let me thank you all the users who posted a comment/answer. Following the suggestions given in the comments and answers, I came up with the following solution. The idea is to add two lists as properties of `Indicator`: `self.adds` and `self.linked`.

- The list `self.adds` collects the addends of the summation. It gets filled up when `__add__` is called. So, in the example below, `ind1.adds is []` and `ind2.adds is []` since both objects don't arise from a sum. On the contrary, `new.adds is [ind1,ind2]`
- The list `self.linked` collects all those object that needs to be updated whenever `self` gets updated. In the example below, `ind1.linked is [new]` and `ind2.linked is [new]`.

I am not completely satisfied with this solution. For example, it fails to work if we sum up three objects and then modify one of them. I can try to fix the code, but I am wondering if I am doing something unconventional. Any thoughts? The code is the following

```
from __future__ import annotations
import copy


class Indicator:
    def __init__(self, elements=None):
        if elements is None:
            self._elements = {}
        else:
            self._elements = elements
        self.adds = []
        self.linked = []

    @property
    def elements(self):
        return self._elements

    @elements.setter
    def elements(self, value):
        self._elements = value
        for i in range(len(self.linked)):
            el = self.linked[i]
            el.update()

    def update(self):
        summation = self.adds[0]
        for obj in self.adds[1:]:
            summation = summation.__add__(obj)
        self._elements = summation.elements

    def __add__(self, other: Indicator):
        new = copy.deepcopy(self)
        self.linked.append(new)
        other.linked.append(new)
        new.adds = [self, other]
        new._elements = {k: self.elements.get(k, 0) + other.elements.get(k, 0) for k in
                         set(self.elements) | set(other.elements)}
        return new


ind1 = Indicator({1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3})
ind2 = Indicator({1: 1, 2: 2})

new = ind1 + ind2
print('ind1: ', ind1.elements)
print('ind2: ', ind2.elements)
print(new.elements)  # {1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 3}
ind1.elements = {0: 0, 1: 3}
print('Updating ind1: ',new.elements == (ind1+ind2).elements)

ind2.elements = {0: 0, 7: 9}
print('Updating ind2: ',new.elements == (ind1+ind2).elements)
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but don't use a dictionary literal as a default value. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: To implement what you want, all the instances that are used in the summation will need a reference to the instance that contains the sum. Then whenever you change the value of one of those instances, it calls a method of the sum instance to update its total.

Comment: There's no built-in way to make this happen AFAIK.

Comment: You have to create your own class derived from "dict" which sends notifications if their values are changed.

Comment: @MichaelButscher can you provide a simple implementation of what you are thinking?

Comment: Does this returned object also need to be an `Indicator` or can it be some other class?

Comment: @tdelaney the returned object has to be an `Indicator`

Comment: This is not a simple task, asking someone to write it for you seems inappropriate. I explained the general approach, now it's your job as the programmer to implement it.

Comment: @Barmar I thought it was a simple task, my bad. I would never ask someone to write a code for me. I will think about a solution based on these comments. Thanks!

Comment: @Barmar I updated the post with a partial solution. It works great with two objects but it fails if I sum up three objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I combined @MichaelButscher's suggestion and your update into one bit of code. I added objects' names and kept the `print` in `notify` for demonstration purpose; note that the `diff` argument in `notify` means that it only works for numerical values (but then, since you implement an `__add__` method, that shouldn't be a problem!).

```
class Indicator(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.derived=[]
        self.name = kwargs['name']

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.notify(key, value - self.get(key,0))
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        
    def __add__(self, other: Indicator):
        new = Indicator({k:self.get(k,0)+other.get(k,0) for k in self.keys()|other.keys()},
                        name=self.name + '+' + other.name)
        self.derived.append(new)
        other.derived.append(new)
        return new
        
    def notify(self, key, diff):
        print(f'Indicator {self.name} : key {key} changed/added')
        for ind in self.derived:
            ind[key] = diff + ind.get(key,0)
```

**Examples**

```
a = Indicator({1:1,2:2}, name = 'a')
b=Indicator({0:3,1:7}, name = 'b')
x=a+b
print(x)
# {0: 3, 1: 8, 2: 2, 'name': 'a+b'}

a[1]=10
# Indicator a : key 1 changed/added
# Indicator a+b : key 1 changed/added
print(x)
# {0: 3, 1: 17, 2: 2, 'name': 'a+b'}

y = x + b
a[10]=77
# Indicator a : key 10 changed/added
# Indicator a+b : key 10 changed/added
# Indicator a+b+b : key 10 changed/added
print(x)
# {0: 3, 1: 17, 2: 2, 'name': 'a+b', 10: 77}
print(y)
# {0: 6, 1: 24, 2: 2, 'name': 'a+b+b', 10: 77}
```

Comment: This is cool! Clean code and it also works for more than two objects. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A very rough idea how this can be done (with a lot of work left to you):

```
class dict_obs(dict):
    def __init__(self, observer, *args, **kwargs):
        self._observer = observer
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._observer.notify(key)
        super().__setitem__(key, value)


class Indicator:
    def notify(self, key):
        print(f"{key} changed")



observer = Indicator()

d = dict_obs(observer, {1:1,2:2,3:3})

d[2] = 5
```

Prints

```
2 changed
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to get inspiration from this answer

Comment: I haven't thought about implementing your answer but I came up with a partial solution (see edited post). It works great with two objects but it fails if I sum up three objects.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is with this line:

```
new.values =  {k: self.elements.get(k, 0) + other.elements.get(k, 0) for k in set(self.elements) | set(other.elements)}
```

You are creating sets of k:v pairs when you really only want the keys. Here is a working solution:

```
class Indicator:
    def __init__(self, elements={}):
        self.elements = elements
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        keys = set(self.elements.keys()).union(set(other.elements.keys()))
        new = {}
        for k in keys:
            new[k] = self.elements.get(k,0) + other.elements.get(k,0)
        return Indicator(new)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP